# How do I make a USB RS232 dongle show up in /dev/ttyUSB*?

Tags: 10.04, usb

I have a couple of FTDI based USB to Rs232 serial dongles. Sometimes when I plug them into my Ubuntu 10.04 laptop, they show up as `/dev/ttyUSB0` and `/dev/ttyUSB1`, which is what I want to have happen. But sometimes they don't. When they don't, sometimes rebooting fixes the problem and sometimes it doesn't. They always show up in `lsusb` hanging off of Bus 5:

```
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I can see them if I do `ls /dev/bus/usb/005` as `002` and `003`. But if I pass `/dev/bus/usb/005/002` to `pyserial`, which is what I'm using to access `/dev/ttyUSBx`, I get `SerialException("Could not open port: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/bus/usb/005/002'",)`.

Comment: Don't access /dev/bus/usb/* with pyserial It is a direct connection to your USB device so you need to talk USB to it, not serial..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the serial device for braille devices, you may wish to disable brltty (you can remove the package), which used to be the culprit for ttyUSB devices at least before Lucid.

I definitely hadn't seen USB RS232 dongles still get claimed by brltty since the Lucid release though.

Comment: This is a pretty common issue among Arduino uC developers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll try it the next time I see the problem and accept your answer then.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the `brltty` package and things seem to work.  @Evan - the USB device in question is based on an FTDI interface, which I think is what's used in Arduino too. Maybe there's an issue specific to that USB chip.

Comment: @mtrw Arduino **does** use the FTDI chip as it's serial/USB interface.